# What are the eigenstate and energy eigenvalues of shifted Harmonic oscillators?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, harmonic-oscillator, quantum-optics

Suppose I have the potential of the shifted harmonic oscillators as
$$H=\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2(x\pm a)^2.$$
Then the energy eigenvalues will be $\hbar\omega(n+\frac{1}{2})$ and eigenfunctions simply as $$\Psi_n(x\pm a)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n n!}}\Big(\frac{m\omega}{\pi \hbar}\Big)^{\frac{1}{4}}e^{-\frac{1}{2\hbar}m\omega (x\pm a)^2}H_n\Big(\sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{\hbar}}(x\pm a)\Big)~?$$

Comment: I would say it is just a matter of redefinition: $x$ is redefined as $y\pm a$ and $y$ is called again $x$. So the brief answer to your question is yes

Comment: Agreed with @RobTan - physically, think about what would happen if you moved $a$ steps to the right or left and then looked at the same system

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thank you very much @RobTan